# Why i can't change JPA version in projects facets to 2.0 in RAD7?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, rad

I'm unable to change the JPA version from **1.0 to 2.0** in **RAD7** , and it's causing me a problem which is :

> NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;

When I go to project facets it's fixed on 1.0 and I can't change it, any help will be highly appreciated.

*NOTE:* if I can't change it I will be glad to know what is the unknown method so I can just remove it depending on how important it is, thanks.

*EDIT:* When I change the version in the header of the presistence.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
<persistence-unit name="ReportManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

I get this error:

> cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value ‘2.0’ of attribute ‘version’ of element
>   ‘entity-mappings’ is not valid with respect to the corresponding
>   attribute use. Attribute ‘version’ has a fixed value of ‘1.0’

Comment: Please show full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You should also upgrade `javax.persistence` from 1.x to 2.x, for example, javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

.